# java card decompile operation from ".cap file"

Tags: java, applet, javacard

I am trying to decompile one ".cap" file which has no ".exp" file or ".class" file. We have lost other files. When I read the javacard documents I found ".cap file" contains ".exp file" information in it. Is it possible to create ".exp file" from ".cap file"?

Answer (score 1):

JCVM specification Chapter 5 handles the Export file format. You can rebuild an export file if you have the neccesary information. It might become easier when you compile a sample applet and analyse the bytes manually.
It's not trivial but don't worry, it only got about 40 bytes.

e: My answer was suggesting that you do not have any unknown exports

Comment: I create new .exp file and run "normalizer.bat normalize -i pepurse" and get [ INFO: ] Cap File to Class File conversion in process.
pepurse (Access is denied).

Comment: Which decompiler are you using?

Comment: I also try to use converter.bat inside JCDK tools and I open my CAP file with pyapdutool and get AID information from that application and give it to converter.bat and exp file but every time I get 
error: invalid AID   zôÙBG:┼▬∟   ∟   ←   pepurse/javacard/Header.cap☺ ↓Ì╩ ÿ☻☻♦ ☺½   ☺◄◄pepursePK♥♦.

Comment: Could you please recommend a decompiler tool to me because I tried JReversePro to use but I couldn' t use that tool properly. I am new for jcdk. I decide to use normalize and converter bat files to convert cap file to jar file.

Comment: @AlptekinTopal [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/) has worked for me. Some people praise [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler). Good luck!